# How can I show FBML tabs on mobile

Tags: html, facebook, mobile, fbml

I know how to make these tabs: https://www.facebook.com/youseedanmark/app_129835087123805 on Facebook. But it won't show them on mobile. How do I fix that. Bear with me if this is a repost, but I really couldn't find this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it won't show them on mobile. How do I fix that.

Not at all. Because page tab apps are not available one the mobile version of Facebook – by design.